# Unable to set ContentTemplate via DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, binding, datatrigger, contentcontrol

I want the `ContentTemplate` to vary according to the value in the `DataTrigger`.
And yes, I considered using a `DataTemplateSelector`, but now I need a `DataTrigger` or better said a `MultiDataTrigger`.

Please take a look at the following sample app, the `DataTemplate` doesn't change:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Content="BoolProperty"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Content="Template 1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Content="Template 2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
        <Button Name="btnSwitch" Content="Switch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```vb
Partial Class Window1
    Public Property BoolProperty() As Boolean
        Get
            Return GetValue(BoolPropertyProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            SetValue(BoolPropertyProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly BoolPropertyProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BoolProperty", GetType(Boolean), GetType(Window1), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(False))

    Private Sub btnSwitch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSwitch.Click
        BoolProperty = Not BoolProperty
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's something that works for me:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeBool}">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PinkTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Pink" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LimeTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Lime" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
  <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl Name="cc"
                      Content="{Binding}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PinkTemplate}" />
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="cc" 
                  Property="ContentTemplate"
                  Value="{StaticResource LimeTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Note that my DataTemplate is another ContentControl, which allows my DataTemplate.Triggers to operate on the ContentTemplate of that (nested) ContentControl.

Comment: If it helps any: You may get an exception unless you change StaticResource to DynamicResource.

Answer (score 16):

I know the OP has no use for this answer anymore but I thought I'd answer it anyway in case anyone else comes along with the same problem

The only problem with the Xaml in the question is that the ContentTemplate is set explicilty on the ContentControl and not in the Style and this overrides the Trigger. Setting it in the Style instead fixes the problem

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Content="Template 2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Content="Template 1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BoolProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type src:Window1}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```