# Switch control template of listview when clicking a button

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

Is it possible to set the control template of my listview with xaml when I click a button?

Right now I know how to set my contenttemplate when I have my `ListViewItem` selected, but not how to change my control template when something outside of the listview changes.

I'd like to change my `ListItemTemplate` to use the `RentTemplate` or the `BuyTemplate` when clicking the corresponding button.

```
    <Button x:Name="RentButton" />
    <Button x:Name="BuyButton" />

    <ListView Name="ItemsList">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <!-- unselected item template -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>
            <!-- selected item template -->
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItemTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="RentTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="BuyTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <!-- set properties for all items -->
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultItemTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <!-- change what the selected item looks like -->
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplate}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

**Edit**

I'm trying to use DataTriggers to select what template to use when I change a property (which I'll change when I click my buttons). I don't think this situation is ideal, but I don't know any other way.

The problem now is that I can't seem to mix Property triggers and DataTriggers in the same MultiTrigger.

The scenario I'm trying to make is the following:
If I push the `BuyButton` I want to see the `BuyTemplate`.
Same for `RentButton` with `RentTemplate`.
BUT when I press a third button `OverviewButton` I'd like to make a choice between two templates, depending on whether the current `ListBoxItem` is selected or not.

Or am I misusing DataTemplates and DataTriggers and is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- unselected item template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- selected item template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItemTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RentTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BuyTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Overview" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultItemTemplate}" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Overview" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplate}" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Rent">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RentTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedType}" Value="Buy">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BuyTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Seems you are searching for a `DataTemplateSelector`. See for example this tutorial: http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: @FlatEric: I'd post that as an answer, with an example of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ultimately solved it like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="OverviewListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultItemTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BuyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BuyTemplate}" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RentListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RentTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```

And just doing this in my view:

```
    private void RentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsList.ItemContainerStyle = (System.Windows.Style)Resources["RentListViewItemStyle"];
        _MainWindowViewModel.RentButton_Click();
    }

    private void BuyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsList.ItemContainerStyle = (System.Windows.Style)Resources["BuyListViewItemStyle"];
        _MainWindowViewModel.BuyButton_Click();
    }

    private void PropertyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsList.ItemContainerStyle = (System.Windows.Style)Resources["OverviewListViewItemStyle"];
        _MainWindowViewModel.PropertyButton_Click();
    }
```

This was the easiest way to switch styles without losing too much time with figuring out the right combination of voodoo and Triggers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DataTemplateSelector`.
A tutorial can be found here:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Some code from the tutorial:

```
public class ImgStringTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        String path = (string)item;
        String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) && ext == ".jpg")
            return ImageTemplate;
        return StringTemplate;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:RelativeToAbsolutePathConverter x:Key="relToAbsPathConverter" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="stringTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
      <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource relToAbsPathConverter}}" 
             Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="200"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ImgStringTemplateSelector 
        ImageTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplate}" 
        StringTemplate="{StaticResource stringTemplate}" 
        x:Key="imgStringTemplateSelector" />
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=PathCollection}" 
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}">
</ListView>
```

The templates and the selector can be specidifed in the resources, the control must then reference the DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: How would I use my button click to change the selected template? I've read [in an other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2089272/1653998) that choosing the template is an event that only happens once.

Comment: Maybe this post will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715315/how-to-trigger-datatemplateselector-when-property-changes

Comment: Eric, I've tried applying those suggestions and have edited my question.